# Wrong 3D Cursor - Far away from the scene

Tags: 3d-cursor

I'm using Blender 2.76 under Windows.
Every time when I try to position the 3D Cursor, one coordinate is set too far away from the screen - e.g.:

1. I load the startup file.
2. I press <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to enter "front ortho" view.
3. I left-click beneath the cube.

I get a 'Y' coordinate of -260.91177!! - which is very far in the front of the scene.

So, it is impossible to place a new object ...

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to re center the 3D cursor in your scene, if this solves your problem you will want to re-save your startup file (File> Save Startup File) so you don't have to re-center the cursor every time you restart Blender.

Comment: It's not a problem with centering the 3D cursor.
The problem is: It is impossible to position the 3D cursor to a usable coordinate **by mouse-click**. Every time I click one or two coordinates are extremly high (see my example). The 3D cursor will be positioned very far in front of the scene.

Comment: Do you have the "Cursor Depth" option enabled on the "Interface" tab of the user preferences?

Comment: That's it! After disabling the "Cursor Depth" option everything works fine.
Thanx!